# Efficient algorithm to find if a value changed dropped or raised in a given time period

Tags: algorithm, minmax

I have to process a csv file with millions of lines "value, datetime": I need to find if the value shifted (drop or raise) by GAP_VALUE (first parameter ) within a given time period TIME_GAP (second parameter).

I am not able to find an efficient algorithm to perform this analysis.

I tried to analyze the csv file line by line:

1. Choose (TIME_GAP, GAP_VALUE) parameters for the analysis.
2. Creating the data subset

- Get the current datetime, the UPPER_TIME_BOUND
- Substract the **TIME_GAP** to find the LOWER_TIME_BOUND
- Extract all data >= LOWER_TIME_BOUND && <= UPPER_TIME_BOUND

3. Detect the drop or the raise within the data subset (not sure about my method)

- Find MAX_VALUE and MIN_VALUE in the extracted dataset (not sure about that because of the data high fluctuation)
- Substract MIN_VALUE to MAX_VALUE to find the VALUE_SHIFT (the datetime order is important to detect if it is a drop or a raise)
- If the VALUE_SHIFT >= **GAP_VALUE** output the datetime when it occured and the shift value.

3. Do the same for the next line in the csv file
4. If (TIME_GAP, GAP_VALUE) parameters change, redo the test.

My algorithm is highly resources-consuming. Could you help me to find a more efficient one please?

Thank you, BR.

Comment: Hi. There are several things ambiguous about the problem you describe. Is `time_gap` an interval like (t0, t1), or a duration t? If it's a duration, do you want to find all value shifts that happened in less than this duration?

Comment: Also, is your data sorted by time? That seems like it would help a lot.

Comment: Also, could you include an example in your question? Something small with maybe only ten lines. That would help us tremendously to understand your problem.

Comment: @Stef TIME_GAP is a configurable duration (1 minute or 1 hour or 1 day)

Comment: @Stef Yes the data is acquired over time so the data is sorted by increasing time

Answer (score 0):

You need a sorted list of counting buckets of values within the current sliding window. (E.g. a `sorted_map<value, counter> buckets`)

I assume you already know how to walk a sliding window over an already sorted set of entry lines in `O(n)`, so I'm only going to describe the actions you need to take on the corresponding window updates.

```
after_increment_window:
    buckets.emplace_if_missing(window.newest.value, 0)
    ++buckets[window.newest.value]
    if(buckets.last.key - buckets.first.key > threshold)
        // You got a match.
before_decrement_window:
    --buckets[window.oldest.value]
    if(bucket[window.oldest.value] == 0)
        // This is where buckets.last and buckets.first can change.
        buckets.remove(window.oldest.value)
```

The requirement for a *sorted* list of buckets gives a runtime of `O(n * log(m))` and a space complexity of `O(m)` with `n` being the total number of entry lines and `m` being the maximum number of unique values within the window size.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you describe this as a 2-step process?

You have to read all the lines (if the lines were sorted by time and of fixed length you may try a binary search, since some `seek` calls could be dramatically faster than reading everything; but usually lines in a CSV file vary in length, so the only possibility is reading them all).

But while you read a line you can check whether it is in the requested time range, and if yes then you can update `min_value` and `max_value`, and the time they happened.

As soon as one of the two values changes, you check if the new delta is exceeding `gap_value`: if yes you can exit and return the two events, else you continue reading.

This is definitely O(n) in time, and O(1) in space.

Another thing: if the file is always the same, and continues increasing, while reading you could store elsewhere some "milestone" position, e.g. 00:00 of each day, or whatever. So at the next run you would not need to read from the beginning of file, but just from the appropriate milestone.

**EDIT**
Seeing the comments by @Ext3h I think my answer is not clear enough. So here is a sample Python implementation:

```
def find_shifts(upper_time_bound, time_gap, gap_value, filename):
    #assume the file contains just the time point and the value in that order
    #assume the file is not sorted
    lower_time_bound = upper_time_bound - time_gap
    min_val = None
    with open(filename, newline='') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile) 
        for row in reader:
            if lower_time_bound <= row[0] <= upper_time_bound:
                if not min_val: #we still need to init the bookkeeping vars
                    min_val = max_val = row[1]
                    min_val_time = max_val_time = row[0]
                else:
                    must_check = False
                    if row[1] < min_val:
                        must_check = True
                        min_val = row[1]
                        min_val_time = row[0]
                    elif row[1] > max_val:
                        must_check = True
                        max_val = row[1]
                        max_val_time = row[0]
                    if must_check:
                        if max_val - min_val > gap_value:
                            return min_val, min_val_time, nax_val, max_val_time
        return False #no shifts detected
```

Comment: It's not `O(n)` time if you go for `O(1)` space. You forgot that whenever you have to update min/max, you will end up with another linear scan of the entire current time window to find the new min/max. Which puts your algorithm at `O(n^2)` time complexity.

Comment: No, just read each line and check if it is a new minimum or a new maximum, and if that is the case update some extra variables, and check if we got a match. One loop, and 4 extra variables

Comment: And that inner loop itself is already `O(n)`.  You lost, your entire algorithm is `O(n^2)` due to that inner loop.